# How to retrain more than the final layer of inception

Tags: tensorflow

I have used the retrain.py script provided at the [tensorflow github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) to finetune a pretrained inceptionV3 model on my own dataset. I have the model saved to disk and now I want to use it as the starting point for another round of training in which I retrain all of the convolutional layers. Below is the code I am attempting to use to create the new graph. I thought that once I have the graph loaded into the default graph I could access the variables in it with tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) and set them all to trainable. However, there doesn't appear to be anything in any of the tf.GraphKeys variables (GLOBAL_VARIABLES, TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, MODEL_VARIABLES etc.). So when I try to create the optimizer I get an error "ValueError: No variables to optimize." What am I doing wrong?

```
def create_graph(model_path, class_count):
    """Creates a graph from saved GraphDef file and returns a saver."""
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    # Creates graph from saved graph_def.pb.
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(model_path, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    #import logits from saved graph
    logits_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name("final_training_ops/biases/final_biases:0")
    ground_truth_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                    [None, class_count],
                                    name='GroundTruthInput')

    print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)              

    #connect logits to the training ops
    with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
        cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
           labels=ground_truth_input, logits=logits_tensor)
    with tf.name_scope('total'):
        cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
    tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy', cross_entropy_mean)

    with tf.name_scope('train'):
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
        train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy_mean)

return graph, ground_truth_input, cross_entropy_mean, train_step
```